# Geoprocessing Service to return Multidimensional Raster from a NetCDF file

Tags: raster, time, netcdf

I have tried to make this work for weeks with no results. I am trying to create a model in ArcMap that uses the Multidimension Tool "Make NetCDF Raster Layer" and return a raster to which I can apply a Time Slider with the Silverlight API once its result is published as a Geoprocessing Service (ArcGis 10.1).
If I create such model and run it in ArcMap, and then publish the result, then I can successfully call the service as an ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer and link a Time Slider to it on my web app. But these type of NetCDF files contain more than one variable and for obvious reasons I want to be able to select any of such variables from my web app and get a different raster (with its time dimension) for each one of them.
So it occurred to me that I could publish a model that gets the variable by input parameter and automatically generates the raster I need. But when I run this Geoprocessing Service and assign the resulting raster to an ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer within the Silverlight environment I get a Raster that I can display but it doesn't have a time dimension/extent.

Any suggestions?